How to get zone-specific stock information for materials?
Problem Description:
I'm working with a federated GraphQL setup involving three services: Material, Zone, and Stock. Each service has its own type definitions:

Zone Service:

Extends the Material type and associates it with zones.

extend type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
}

type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  materials: [Material!]!
}

type Query {
  zones: [Zone!]!
}


Material Service:

Provides information about the materials.

type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  materials: [Material!]!
}


Stock Service:

Extends Material to add stocks, with each stock being associated with both a materialId and zoneId.

extend type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  stocks: Stock!
}

type Stock {
  amount: Int!
}

type Query {
  stocks: [Stock!]!
}



The Stock type has a zoneId and materialId:
const stocks = [
  { id: "1", zoneId: "1", materialId: "1", amount: 100 },
  { id: "2", zoneId: "1", materialId: "2", amount: 50 },
  { id: "3", zoneId: "2", materialId: "2", amount: 80 },
  { id: "4", zoneId: "2", materialId: "3", amount: 120 },
];

When I run the following query, I want the stocks field to return the correct stock based on the zoneId:
query Zones {
  zones {
    id
    name
    materials {
      id
      name
      stocks {
        amount
      }
    }
  }
}

Issue: The stocks field returns stock information without considering the zoneId properly. Instead of getting the stock specific to the zoneId and materialId, it always returns a stock value that does not properly match the context.
Result:
{
  "data": {
    "zones": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Zone A",
        "materials": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Sand",
            "stocks": { "amount": 100 }
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Gravel",
            "stocks": { "amount": 50 }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Zone B",
        "materials": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Gravel",
            "stocks": { "amount": 50 } // should be 80 for Zone B
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Cement",
            "stocks": { "amount": 120 }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Question: How can I ensure that the stocks field on Material returns the correct stock specific to both materialId and zoneId? Should I extend Material differently or add more information in the Zone service to achieve this?
Example Project: I have an example project setup that might help explain the issue more: GitHub Repository

So this might not answer your question the way you want it to, but IMO the answer is that your schema is "wrong" for the data you're trying to display. What you're describing sounds to me like an entity all its own. It sounds like a Zone has instances of Stock which in turn has a reference to the Material that it is for.
Notes:

In my examples, I've changed your word Stock to the word Inventory to more closely match examples like Shopify's GraphQL API. You can change it back to Stock if that's easier for you.
I'm making the assumption from your question that you're using current Apollo Federation. This means I can use @inaccessible (explained here) and I can leave out @external when used in fields (explained here). I added an example at the end if you're not, but I would avoid that if you can. Apollo Federation v1 is reaching EoL (end of life) soon if it hasn't already.

If the existence of inventory is the source of truth of materials in a zone
Zone Service: remove all reference to Material, making this a stand-alone service
type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  zones: [Zone!]!
}

Material Service: no change
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  materials: [Material!]!
}

Inventory Service: Bridges the gaps
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
}

type Inventory {
  material: Material!
  zone: Zone!
  amount: Int!
}

type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  inventories: [Inventory!]!
}

type Query {
  inventories: [Inventory!]!
}

If the Zone service materials is the source of truth, irrespective of if there is an Inventory entry or not
Zone subgraph: add materialIds as an @inaccessible property and remove all reference to Material
type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  materialIds: [ID!]! @inaccessible
}

type Query {
  zones: [Zone!]!
}

Material Service: no change
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  materials: [Material!]!
}

Stock Subgraph: Add Inventory from materialIds
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
}

type Inventory {
  material: Material!
  zone: Zone!
  amount: Int!
}

type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  materialIds: [ID!]! @external
  inventories: [Inventory!]! @requires(fields: "materialIds")
}

type Query {
  inventories: [Inventory!]!
}

If using Apollo Federation v1
Zone service: add all Inventory (but without the numbers)
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
}

type Inventory @key(fields: "material { id } zone { id }") {
  material: Material!
  zone: Zone!
}

type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  inventories: [Inventory!]!
}

type Query {
  zones: [Zone!]!
}

Material Service: no change
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  materials: [Material!]!
}

Stock Service: only fill in the numbers for Inventory
type Material @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
}

type Stock @key(fields: "material { id } zone { id }") {
  # Note: I don't remember if these `@external` are needed or not
  material: Material! @external
  zone: Zone! @external
  amount: Int!
}

type Zone @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  inventories: [Inventory!]!
}


Extra Credit Note on Inventory.zone
Technically, returning a property Inventory.zone is optional (except in the case of the non-fedV2+), but I left it there, since you have top-level queries for stocks in your question. Just so you know, if you don't actually have a use-case for loading all stocks, and if that's only there for testing, you should be aware that you can query an Apollo Subgraph the same way the Supergraph routers work: using the _entities "secret query". These Federation queries aren't available from the client when querying the supergraph, but they're how the Supergraph works internally.
e.g. This query is what the Supergraph would use to fetch (from the Inventory subgraph) the inventories property on a Zone (which was returned from the Zones Subgraph):
query ($_representations: [_Any!]!) {
  _entities(representations:$_representations) {
    ... on Zone {
      id
      inventories {
        material { id }
        amount
      }
    }
  }
}

You can read more about the internal queries in this blog post, but do note that it has the same opinion as me (because I wrote it).
